# Ethernet frames from NIC

Tags: linux, ethernet, nic

I'm searching for help and an opinion-advice for a network project, in which I'm working lately. This requires a Linux machine to be a passive network appliance.

Network packets come in from one network interface and come out from another interface ( net--eth0-->Linux PC--eth1-->net) without making any modifications on data.

The application, which is going to run on the Linux system, will change only the order of the packets. It is going to be a "silly" network emulator application.

The first implementation was made with RAW sockets, where read() is called every time a packet arrives to user space and write() is called when an Ethernet packet should be sent down to the NIC.

I would like to know if there is a more practical and direct way than RAW sockets, bypassing Linux's network stack.

Comment: you can't bypass the Linux network stack and they way you are doing it is probably the easiest way.
What do you mean by practical?

Comment: The practical way goes to the technical part of the implementation. Sockets implementation requires a tx-rx mechanism with non blocking IO, this is how I Implemented on first place utilizing select() and pthreads under C. Is there a better design philosophy?

Also I'm searching a way where the intermediate system is not going to process all that network traffic. Only the emulation application should run between the two interfaces.

Comment: What you could do is create a `netfilter` hook and have it receive your packets and then send them immediately. This way your packets won't have to travel to the userspace and you can do the processing inside the Kernel space which is faster.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to bypass the kernel, DPDK in Linux and NetMap in FreeBSD are options to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this can be done in dpdk in Linux. There are l3fw and l2fwd sample applications in the examples folder of the dpdk tree, which may inspire you. Also consider using vpp, a fd.io project hosted by Linux Foundation, which can use dpdk.

Rami Rosen